# Why the speed of a node is getting faster and faster when a button is pressed in spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift

As the title suggests, every time I tap a button node, an item node gets faster. How am I able to keep the speed consistent? **This is the code for the function.**

```
let ball: Ball = Ball(textureName: "ball.png")
func attackButton() {

    ball.removeFromParent()

    ball.position = CGPointMake(100, hero.position.y)
    ball.startMoving()
    hero.throwBall() // for just movement of his arm
    playThrowSound()
    addChild(ball)

}

func startMoving() {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 3)
    ball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))

    let rotating = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 6)
    ball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotating))
}
```

Also, though this code works, but not in my desired way. After a ball is produced, the ball is deleted and the next ball is produced. I know this is because of the `removeFromParent()`, but I cannot figure out other ways. I want that once produced ball to be deleted only when it is off the screen.

So I really appreciate if you give me solutions for those two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It doesn't make sense to run the action forever to move by 200 points in 3 seconds. That's why your ball keeps moving too fast. the previous action is in effect even if the node was removed because it's the same variable that you're applying the action.

If you want to remove it after it comes off the screen, then you can do 2 things: calculate when the balls position is outside the view, or remove it after a couple of seconds (however long it takes to move out of the scene).

To remove after getting out of the view, you can do this. Add this code anywhere as global variables or inside a class.

```
//Used to get the ratio of the device for later calculation
var deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
var deviceHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
var playableArea: CGRect!
```

Depending on the orientation, choose one and add it to the didMoveToView()

```
//USE THIS FOR PORTRAIT
 let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = deviceHeight / deviceWidth
 let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
 let playableMargin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2.0
 playableArea = CGRect(x: playableMargin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

 //USE THIS FOR LANDSCAPE
 let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = deviceWidth / deviceHeight
 let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
 let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight) / 2.0
 playableArea = CGRect(x:0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)
```

What this code does it draws a rectangular frame that surrounds the entire view of the phone that the user is able to see. [Explanation from my Github](https://github.com/jozemite/SpriteKit-Playable-Area). Now you just have to check if the position of the ball is outside the playableArea rectangle.

```
if ball.x > playableArea.x || ball.x < playableArea.x {
    //If the ball has moved out of the view horizontally
    runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration: 0.5, ball.removeFromParent()]))
} else if ball.y > playableArea.y || ball.y < playableArea.y {
    //If the ball has moved out of the view vertically
    runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration: 0.5, ball.removeFromParent()]))
}
```

You could also make the ball a local variable inside the function that creates it, and do something like this:

If you want to remove it after a few seconds, then use SKAction sequence. But I recommend you put the ball variable inside the function that adds it to the view. This will prevent "node already has a parent" errors.

```
ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 3), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you add the code for your `Ball-Class`? I guess that in your **`Ball-Class` is the Problem for your app crashing**. In the function `attackButton` you are removing and adding the `ball` to the Scene. But i think in your `Ball-Class` you are adding a SKNode but you don't remove it there, too. So the code below should work if you fixed the Problem in your `Ball-Class` (you did not post the Code - so you have to check that yourself).

```
let ball: Ball = Ball(textureName: "ball.png")

func attackButton() {
    ball.removeFromParent()
    ball.position = CGPointMake(100, hero.position.y)
    hero.throwBall() // for just movement of his arm
    playThrowSound()
    addChild(ball)
    ball.startMoving()
}

func startMoving() {
    ball.removeAllActions()
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 3)
    ball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))

    let rotating = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 6)
    ball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotating))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to remove last `SKAction` and then run the new action when you call startMoving function. You can use `removeAllActions()` of `removeActionForKey("")`

Comment: Not working. There is an error message saying "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:

Comment: That means you're adding a sprite that already exists and you didn't remove. It's like me adding ball to the scene and then adding it again without removing the last one.

Comment: FYI that happens because ball is not a local variable.

Comment: I attempted, but it does not succeed for now. If I write it as local, the existing code that is used as global right now becomes unable to function, because it is written inside the 'didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)' method. Since it is used as global now, it is fine. To fix this, is there any way?